# Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial such that for all integers $x$, $P(x)$ is an integer.

Tags: polynomials

Show that if $P(x)$ is written as $c_n \binom{x}{n}+c_{n-1}\binom{x}{n-1}+\cdots+c_0 \binom{x}{0}$, then $c_i$ is an integer for $0\le i \le n$

What I have: I know all the $c_i$ are unique, and $c_0$ must be an integer, so any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: plug in $x=1$. then $c_0$ integer implies $c_1$ integer. then plug in $x=2$. then $c_0,c_1$ integers imply $c_2$ integer. etc

Comment: according to me, ${1 \choose n} = 0$ if $n > 1$.

Comment: Oh wait you're right. Thank you! To close the topic I'll just write a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight is to use induction and plug simple values of $x$.

First of all, note that $P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. I claim $c_0$ is an integer. Note that $c_0=a_0$ because when written as $c_n\binom{x}{n}+\cdots+c_0$, all other terms are nonconstant. Let $y$ be any positive integer such that $y$ multiplied by any one of $a_n,\cdots a_0$ is an integer, so $P(y)-P(0)$ is an integer, but $P(y)$ is also an integer, so $P(0)=a_0=c_0$ is an integer.

I claim $c_i$ is an integer where $0\le i \le n$ Let's use induction on $i$.

The base case, $i=0$ is proven above.

Inductive Step: By definition of $\binom{x}{n}$, if we know the values of $x$ and $n$, and $x<n$, then $\binom{x}{n}=0$. Assume $c_{i-1}, c_{i-2}, \cdots c_0$ are all integers. I just need to show that $c_i$ is an integer.

Plug $x=i$. Since $P(i)$ is an integer, and $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} c_j \binom{i}{j}$ is an integer by inductive hypothesis, $c_i\binom{i}{i}=c_i$ must be an integer. That completes our induction and the conclusion follows.

Comment: why can't you show $c_0$ is an integer just by plugging in $x=0$? also, OP said they knew $c_0$ is an integer

Comment: You're right. I missed that.